# how to enable java file in realm to all users

Tags: web-services, jdbcrealm

i have a web service that i want to enable for use to all users (web service is written as java class). I use realm to configure my website security. How can i enable this resource in web.xml?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This allows everyone (without login) to access the resource (there is no `auth-constraint` tag):

```
 <security-constraint> 
    <web-resource-collection> 
      <web-resource-name>MyWebService</web-resource-name>       
      <url-pattern>/public/webservice</url-pattern>      
    </web-resource-collection>     
  </security-constraint>
```

This allows the logged in users (which has at least one role from the `security-role` list) to access the resource:

```
<security-constraint> 
    <web-resource-collection> 
        <web-resource-name>MyWebService</web-resource-name>       
        <url-pattern>/public/webservice</url-pattern>      
    </web-resource-collection> 
    <auth-constraint>      
        <role-name>*</role-name> 
    </auth-constraint> 
</security-constraint> 

<security-role>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
    <role-name>manager</role-name>
</security-role>
```